# filter KeyValueGrouped Dataset in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have a typed dataset of a custom class and use groupbykey method on it. You know that it results a KeyValueGroupedDataset. I want to filter this new dataset but there is no filter method for this type of dataset. So, My question is: How can I filter on this type of dataset? (Java solution is needed. spark version: 2.3.1).

sampleData:

```
"id":1,"fname":"Gale","lname":"Willmett","email":"gwillmett0@nhs.uk","gender":"Female"
"id":2,"fname":"Chantalle","lname":"Wilcher","email":"cwilcher1@blinklist.com","gender":"Female"
"id":3,"fname":"Polly","lname":"Grandisson","email":"pgrandisson2@linkedin.com","gender":"Female"
"id":3,"fname":"Moshe","lname":"Pink","email":"mpink3@twitter.com","gender":"Male"
"id":2,"fname":"Yorke","lname":"Ginnelly","email":"yginnelly4@apple.com","gender":"Male"
```

And What I did:

```
    Dataset<Person> peopleDS = spark.read().format("parquet").load("\path").as(Encoders.bean(Person.class));
    KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, Person> KVDS = peopleDS.groupByKey( (MapFunction<Person, String> ) f -> f.getGender() , Encoders.STRING());
//How Can I filter on KVDS's id field?
```

**Update1** (use of flatMapGroups):

```
Dataset<Person> persons = KVDS.flatMapGroups((FlatMapGroupsFunction <String,Person,Person>) (f,k) -> (Iterator<Person>) k ,  Encoders.bean(Person.class));
```

**Update2** (use of MapGroups)

```
Dataset<Person> peopleMap = KVDS.mapGroups((MapGroupsFunction <String,Person,Person>) (f,g) -> {
        while (g.hasNext()) {
        //What can I do here?       
    }
},Encoders.bean(Person.Class);
```

**Update3** : I want to filter those groups that distinct of their ids is greater than 1. for example in below picture: I want just Female groups because distinct of their ids is greater that 1 (first field is id. Others are fname,lname,email and gender).
[image]

**Update4:** I did What I want with "RDD", but I want to do exactly this part of code with "Dataset":

```
List<Tuple2<String, Iterable<Person>>> f = PersonRDD
        .mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s.getGender(), s)).groupByKey()
        .filter(t -> ((Collection<Person>) t._2()).stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getId).distinct().count() > 1)
        .collect();
```

Comment: Hard question to follow for me

Comment: Easy form of question: I have a dataset of "person" that is grouped by "gender" and now I want to filter the result. How can I do that?

Comment: Thats real easy

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: I see you updated. Studying for exam but will look in between

Comment: OK slightly different, fine

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have never done a group by like this; so hard for me to think of a solution. Could be done but context escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is used for aggregation functions, you can find functions like "agg" in "KeyValueGroupedDataset" class. If you apply aggregation function for ex. "count", you will get "Dataset", and "filter" function will be available.

"groupBy" without aggregation function looks strange, other function, for ex. "distinct" can be used.

Filtering example with "FlatMapGroupsFunction":

```
                .flatMapGroups(
                    (FlatMapGroupsFunction<String, Person, Person>) (f, k) -> {
                        List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
                        while (k.hasNext()) {
                            Person value = k.next();
                            // filter condition here
                            if (value != null) {
                                result.add(value);
                            }
                        }
                        return result.iterator();
                    },
                    Encoders.bean(Person.class))
```

Comment: I agree with you that: "Grouping is used for aggregation functions", but in this case I does not need aggregate function. I just need gender field as "key" and list of all Objects (Person) as "Value" and then I want to process "Value" by filtering. Is there a better way than groupbykey ?

Comment: For filter just values "flatMapGroups" can be used.

Comment: I update my question with use of flatMapGroup function, but I think flatMapGroups gives me the same dataset before group by.

Comment: please see Update4 of my question. I did what I want with RDD. I want to convert exactly that part to Dataset.

Comment: Dataset can be transformed to RDD and code from "Update4" applied: "ad.rdd().toJavaRDD()"

Comment: I know that dataset can be transformed to RDD, but I want to do that with dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you filter on id before grouping ? GroupByKey is an expensive action, it should be faster to filter first.

If you really want to group first, you may have to then use .flatMapGroups with identity function.

Not sure about java code but scala version would be something as follow:

```
peopleDS
.groupByKey(_.gender)
.mapGroups { case (gender, persons) => persons.filter(your condition) }
```

But again, you should filter first :). Specially since your ID field is already available before grouping.

Comment: I don't filter first because I want different filters for different genders.

Comment: And "mapGroups" give me a iterator of values that I do not know how it can help me. See update2 in my question pls.

Comment: Can you please post your filter logic ? What elements to you want to keep ?
Don't bother with mapGroups, I meant flatMapGroups.